# Non breaking space between date elements word vba

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to make sure the dates stay together and not break across lines.

The replacement text should have two non breaking spaces, one between **\1 April**, and one between **April \2**.

```
Sub SarahDates()
‘ Supposed to put a non breaking space between day, month and year.
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = “([0-9]) April ([0-9])”
        .Replacement.Text = “\1 April \2”
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End Sub
```

What is the correct text in `.Replacement.Text` so that non-breaking spaces are shown in macro.

Comment: What's the question though?  Is something not working out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the following macro will reformat all your dates in one go.

```
Sub SarahDates()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ActiveDocument.Range.Find
  .ClearFormatting
  .Replacement.ClearFormatting
  .Text = "(<[0-9]{1,2}) ([JFMASOND][abceghilmnoprstuvy]{2,8}) ([12][0-9]{3}>)"
  .Replacement.Text = "\1^s\2^s\3"
  .Forward = True
  .Format = False
  .Wrap = wdFindContinue
  .MatchWildcards = True
  .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Please explain how your code includes non-breaking spaces in the dates it formats.

Comment: Look at the .Replacement.Text expression. The ^s denotes a non-breaking space.

Comment: Please incorporate the additional information *in the answer, itself*, using the [edit] link. Comments on Stack Overflow are "ephemeral" - they tend to disappear over time. An explanation of the code *within *an answer is always appreciated by everyone who reads it.

Comment: I wouldn't have thought explaining standard Find/Replace expressions anyone can find for themselves via Word's Find/Replace dialogue was necessary. Frankly, the Find expression is rather more obscure - and I don't propose to add a half-page commentary about that, either.